# How can I find the old wheel file of opencv-python 3.3.1 on this website?

Tags: python, opencv

On this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), I want to find the wheel file of opencv-python.

The version I want is "opencv_python-3.3.1+contrib-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl", but this website is updated. I can't find it. How can I find the old wheel file?

Comment: Couldn't you just search this wheel file in Google?

Comment: Google is also connected to this site.

Comment: The website has deleted the old version.

Comment: @Silencer  The meaning is that if there is no backup, there is no way to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately for you this website has a bunch of backups available to you via wayback machines.

https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I haven't searched through each one for the file you are looking for but if it isn't available through one of those links then it is likely you would need to contact the site administrator for the older files.

Edit: I have searched through and this is the link that contains the file you require:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170818132118/http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: https://web.archive.org  backups the plain content that can be displayed on the web, such as html/image, but doesn't backup the zip/tar.gz/whl. So even you find the link, if the original website has deleted the content, you still can't download. P.S. If you click the link related `opencv 3.3.x`, some info occurs, maybe `The requested resource could not be found.`